# On Bitbucket, how can a Jupyter notebook be rendered for teams?

Tags: bitbucket, jupyter

My development team has a Bitbucket repository that contains Jupyter notebooks. We need these notebooks to render on the Bitbucket website.

I can enable rendering of notebooks in my personal repositories in the following way:

```
avatar at bottom left > Integrations > Bitbucket Notebook Viewer > Add
```

This method does not enable rendering of notebooks in the development team repository.

I attempted to enable rendering for the team repositories in the following way:

```
avatar at bottom left > team name > Settings > Find integrations > Bitbucket Notebook Viewer > Add
```

This has not enabled rendering of the notebooks. What is going wrong? How can I enable rendering of the Jupyter notebooks in the team Bitbucket repository?